# How can I rename a directory in linux with terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-18.04, linux-mint

**scenario**: I have ssh onto a remote server and have created a directory named *helloworld/* and after working with it for some time I wanted to rename it to something like *hello_world/* I was wondering how I can easily do that.

I was looking online and I was not able to find much resources, but I think this is a pretty simple thing, so I imagine there will be a simple way of achieving this.

Please let me know

Comment: I think if you copy the title of your question into your favorite search engine you will probably find hundreds of answers.

Answer (score 2):

`mv <source_directory> <target_directory>`